# How to fix CSS gradient background leaving whitespace at the bottom on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, gradient

I want to fix CSS gradient background on mobile.

Right now, on mobile, when a user zooms into the page and scrolls down, he sees css gradient end and then sees white space. The white space remains there after zooming out. See this [image](https://i.imgur.com/vYry5zl.jpg)

Zooming in/out or scrolling does not seem to cause issues on desktop

The page is currently live at http://beta.qalamproject.com/

I have tried messing around with including the background css in the body selector, instead of html, but can't seem to figure out what is causing the issue.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; */
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%,  rgba(226,240,254,1) 0%, rgba(255,247,228,1) 90% );
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 10em 1em 0em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I expect the background gradient to fill the entire page, regardless of how the user zooms, scrolls, etc. Instead, right now the background ends and user sees white.

Comment: Based on your above code there will be no whitespace. I can only assume it's because you have additional CSS that is setting an overflow, or push the `height` past more than `100%`.

Comment: Only other CSS I have is for the text on the page. The issue is only prevalent on mobile. On desktop, it is good

Comment: Is this happening on all mobile devices or a specific one?

Comment: Try using 100vh instead of 100%, check if it works

Comment: Use height 100vh and remove margins. If you want to contain text, create a container and set a max-width

Comment: Thank you for suggestion of using 100vh. The user still sees white space when I use 100vh, but browser seems to fix it after a second, so I think this may be the best option. However, I noticed that when I use 100%, the page is correctly sized but with 100vh there is extra area to scroll down to. do you know why that is? Not a big issue, just wondering why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background size as **cover**

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%, rgba(226,240,254,1) 0%, rgba(255,247,228,1) 90% );
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. however, this did not fix it, the user still sees white space when they zoom and scroll down

Comment: Ahh that's a shame. Unfortunately I'm having trouble replicating the issue :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the 'height'? I wouldn't usually define a height for my html.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem few days ago, I have solved this by applying background in the pseudo-element.

```css
#___gatsby {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#___gatsby::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: var(--color-background-gradient); /* URL of your image */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I am using Gatsby, `#__gatsby` is the outermost container.

This solution is inspired by an article on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-fixed-background-attachment-hack/) written by Murtuzaali Surti and a comment below by Joseph Levin.
The problem is caused by `background-attachment: fixed;`, which behaves differently on mobile browsers, you could find detailed explaination in the article I have provied.